Is string.indexOf() treated the same on Linux vs Windows?
I'm not an experienced JavaScript programmer.  This is my first project using JS.
I'm developing on Linux and am at the point for my first release.  Running the project on a Windows machine I came across the following ...
const os = require("os");
global.DBSysInfo;

console.log("DBSysInfo =\n" + DBSysInfo);
var pnt1 = DBSysInfo.indexOf('DBActive = "yes"');
console.log("pnt1 = " + pnt1);
var pnt2 = DBSysInfo.indexOf(os.EOL + os.EOL, pnt1) + 1;
console.log("pnt1 = " + pnt1 + "; pnt2 = " + pnt2);
console.log("DBSysInfo.substring =\n" + DBSysInfo.substring(pnt1, pnt2));

The above code works as expected on Linux:
DBSysInfo =
SysLocation = "C:\Users\mlake\MELGenKey"  
  
DBActive = "yes"  
DBName = "SOT2-KILLE20240704"  
DBUserID = "2.0"  
DBStatus = "1"  
DBSecurity = "0"  
DBLocation = "DBs/SOT2-KILLE20240704"  


pnt1 = 42  
pnt1 = 42; pnt2 = 176  
DBSysInfo.substring =  
DBActive = "yes"  
DBName = "SOT2-KILLE20240704"  
DBUserID = "2.0"  
DBStatus = "1"  
DBSecurity = "0"  
DBLocation = "DBs/SOT2-KILLE20240704"  

On Windows, the output is:
DBSysInfo =  
SysLocation = "C:\Users\mlake\MELGenKey"  
  
DBActive = "yes"  
DBName = "SOT2-KILLE20240704"  
DBUserID = "2.0"  
DBStatus = "1"  
DBSecurity = "0"  
DBLocation = "DBs/SOT2-KILLE20240704"  
  
  
pnt1 = 42  
pnt1 = 42; pnt2 = 0  
DBSysInfo.substring =  
SysLocation = "C:\Users\mlake\MELGenKey"  

I don't understand why the output would be different on Windows.  Why would pnt2 be 0?  The only thing I can think is the second "indexOf" statement is treating "DBSysInfo" as an array.  If so, why?  Is global treated differently on Windows than it is on Linux?
I tried using both Edge and Firefox on Windows with the same results, but the code is in node and I wouldn't think the browser used would make any difference in this instance.

linux and windows do have a different "EOL" convention ... windows \r\n ... linux \n - what is the respective value of os.EOL in your code for linux and windows - perhaps whatever DBSysInfo is always uses the linux "convention" regardless of the OS

indexOf is the same, but i think it's more likely your input is different. Many tools on windows write text files using different line endings for example

Oops yeah I agree with Jaramanda X.

e.g. in windows console.log("\n".length) is 1 but console.log(os.EOL.length) is 2 - so, using the literal \n is not the same as in some environments where \n can be taken to mean \r\n (I can't remember where that was, but I know it was many years ago that this tripped me up)

Note that global.DBSysInfo; is a property access that doesn’t do anything, even as an assertion (if global.DBSysInfo doesn’t exist, there won’t be an error). Not sure if that was the intent.


Is string.indexOf() treated the same on Linux vs Windows?

Yes.

The only thing I can think is the second "indexOf" statement is treating "DBSysInfo" as an array.

That’s possible (not “treating”, but that DBSysInfo is somehow actually an array), but more likely is that the contents of the string aren’t what you expect, and that indexOf is returning −1 because the search pattern actually doesn’t exist in the string. In any case, you can confirm with either a debugger or print debugging:
console.log("%O", DBSysInfo);

The %O format specifier corresponds to inspect-type output that will quote strings, bracket arrays, and display non-printing characters as escapes.
Even on Windows, it’s common to see Unix line endings, so looking strictly for os.EOL is prone to error. A regular expression that allows flexible line endings is a decent alternative to plug in:
let pnt2 = DBSysInfo.indexOf(/(\r?\n){2}/m, pnt1);

Or, if you’re not writing this string back, consider normalizing it as it arrives with .replace(/\r\n/g, "\n"). Then you can search for "\n\n" directly and not have to also potentially worry about how many characters a newline is.

The answers and comments made me realize what was going on. (Kind of a "duh" moment for me!) The contents of "DBSysInfo" comes from reading a file that was created on Linux and just copied over to the Windows machine. The reverse could also happen as the project is used. Thanks, everyone, for
your answers and comments.

Great. Can you please mark my answer if you think it solved your problem

@abuzain, By "mark" do you mean to vote it up or accept it as the best answer?  I think both answers solved my problem.  Can I accept/mark both answers?

I want you to accept, but it's okay if you think this isn't the best answer.
